# Оставить двумерные массивы

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
    [11168] => 0
    [11601] => 1
    [12846] => 2
    [8880] => 3
    [9242] => 4
    [9031] => 5
    [16106] => 6
    [7116] => 7
    [7096] => 8
    [25608] => 9
    [28577] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 
                    [RESTRAURAN_ID] => 
                    [SECTION] => 
                    [LOGO] => 
                    [PRICE] => 
                    [ANONS_MENU] => 
                    [ACTIVE] => 1
                    [NAME] => 
                    [ADDRESS] => 
                    [CITY] => 
                    [METRO] => 
                    [METRO_ID] => 
                    [TYPE] => 
                    [KITCHEN] => 
                    [DELIVERY_CONDITION] => 
                    [CITY_ID] => 
                    [TYPE_ID] => 
                    [KITCHEN_ID] => 
                    [LATITUDE] => 
                    [LONGITUDE] => 
                    [PREVIEW_PICTURE] => 
                    [DETAIL_PAGE_URL] => 
                )
```

)

Как удалить все кроме 28577? И в дальнейшем проверять на вложенность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input_array = YOUR_INPUT_ARRAY;   
foreach ($input_array as $k=>$v){   
   if(!is_array($input_array[$k]))   
       unset($input_array[$k]);
}
```